# How to open an existing program in client device

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have local network, and there is one program related to "library book store search"

this program must be installed in a specific path "`c:\library Search\program.exe`".

I want to add in my local portal button to run this program once click.

I used: "`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe");`" as example and it works in my lab, but on my website "internet" nothing done.

so what is the best way to open this local program from my local portal.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using ASP.NET you can't run exe on your local machine but you can try JavaScript solution like below.

```
<html> 
 <head> 
     <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
         MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" )  
         function RunExe()   
         {  
            MyObject.Run("file:///C:/Program%20Files/EditPlus%203/editplus.exe") ;  
        }  

    </script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
    <h1>Run a Program</h1> 
    This script launch the file any Exe File<p> 
    <button onclick="RunExe()">Run Exe File</button> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

code from [here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19547-Run-exe-file-Java-Script.aspx)

ASP.NET run on server side you need to use client side code like above. but if you have shared location and put your exe there you can access it as below

```
<a href="\\MyServer\SharedFolder\Myprogram.exe" 
  type="application/octet-stream">library book store search</a>
```

Comment: Keep in mind this would require a very low security settings in your clients browser, most likely it would force them to lower their settings far below default values.

Comment: Thanks Damith, but i got this error: 'ASP.test_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'RunExe'!!! i add the code as it is and just add my exe file path, "test.aspx" is page name.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on your lab because you have access rights and physical access to that path. When you `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe");` will always be executing on your server.  You need to use some sort of client side code (IE. Javascript ) to do what you wish, which will most likely require the end user to make adjustments to their browser or allow access.